# A notification dialog with action buttons for video call when app is closed or terminated in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, push-notification, flutter-local-notification

I am using Flutter WebRTC for doing video calls. The video call is working fine. For getting the video call when app is running background or app is closed I am using Firebase Cloud Messaging and I am using firebase messaging package. I am getting the push notification while app is closed and running background. But I am unable to show a dialog like Whatsapp/ Skype/ Messenger notification dialog. I am using flutter local notification package for showing push notification.
[image]
I want to show a dialog shown in the picture.

Also, when the app is closed, if the push notification is clicked, I want to redirect to a desired page. At this moment it is redirecting to splash screen, then home screen, at last to desired screen. How can I redirect at first?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [firebase_messaging](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging) and [awesome_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_notifications)

add this in your firebase background subscription handler

```
await AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
  content: NotificationContent(
    id: createuniqueId(),
    channelKey: 'basic_channel',
    title: message.data['title'],
    body: message.data['body'],
    wakeUpScreen: true,
    fullScreenIntent: true,
    autoDismissible: false,
    category: NotificationCategory.Call,
    locked: true,
    displayOnForeground: true,
  ),
  actionButtons: [
    NotificationActionButton(
      key: 'accept',
      label: 'Accept',
    ),
    NotificationActionButton(
      isDangerousOption: true,
      key: 'reject',
      label: 'Reject',
    ),
  ],
);
```

add this in your main()

```
AwesomeNotifications().initialize(
    'resource://drawable/ic_icon',
    [
      NotificationChannel(
        channelKey: 'basic_channel', 
        channelName: 'Basic Notification', 
        channelDescription: 'Hello world',
        importance: NotificationImportance.High,
        channelShowBadge: true,
        vibrationPattern: highVibrationPattern
      ),
    ]
  );
```

Comment: is it possible using flutter_local_notifications? I am using that package

Comment: of course, you can just add ```actions : []``` in ```AndroidNotificationDetails()``` and ```DarwinNotificationDetails```

Answer (score 0):

Example for `flutter_local_notifications` :

android

```
Future<void> _showNotificationWithActions() async {
  const AndroidNotificationDetails androidNotificationDetails =
      AndroidNotificationDetails(
    '...',
    '...',
    '...',
    actions: <AndroidNotificationAction>[
      AndroidNotificationAction('id_1', 'Action 1'),
      AndroidNotificationAction('id_2', 'Action 2'),
      AndroidNotificationAction('id_3', 'Action 3'),
    ],
  );
  const NotificationDetails notificationDetails =
      NotificationDetails(android: androidNotificationDetails);
  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      0, '...', '...', notificationDetails);
}
```

ios

```
final DarwinInitializationSettings initializationSettingsDarwin = DarwinInitializationSettings(
    // ...
    notificationCategories: [
    const DarwinNotificationCategory(
        'demoCategory',
        <DarwinNotificationAction>[
            DarwinNotificationAction('id_1', 'Action 1'),
            DarwinNotificationAction(
            'id_2',
            'Action 2',
            options: <DarwinNotificationActionOption>{
                DarwinNotificationActionOption.destructive,
            },
            ),
            DarwinNotificationAction(
            'id_3',
            'Action 3',
            options: <DarwinNotificationActionOption>{
                DarwinNotificationActionOption.foreground,
            },
            ),
        ],
        options: <DarwinNotificationCategoryOption>{
            DarwinNotificationCategoryOption.hiddenPreviewShowTitle,
        },
    )
],
```

On iOS notification actions need to be configured before the app is started using the initialize method

Comment: I tried this. But when the app is closed and if I click the action button it doesn’t redirect properly. It goes to splash screen then main screen and then calling screen. I want to redirect directly to calling screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp** to redirect to the desired screen.

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((message) {
  if (message.data['screen'] == 'video_call_screen') {
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/video_call_screen');
  }
});
```

Comment: But when app is terminated,  once the app wake up then it shows the splash screen, then home screen and then shows the video call screen. It is kind of confusing. @Jaspalsinh Gohil How can I solve this issue? mainly when the app is closed